# Invalid property name in character class webpack npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error with npm start. The error is coming from webapp module's RuntimeTemplate. I have tried lowering the version of webpack. The node version is 18.16.0 and typescript version is 5.0.2.

/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuntimeTemplate.js:64
trimmed.match(/^[_\p{L}][_0-9\p{L}]*$/iu) ||
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[_\p{L}][_0-9\p{L}]*$/: Invalid property name in character class
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:53:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)

Node.js v18.16.0
```

Comment: Seems your node runtime has no support for unicode escape character classes. Try to reinstall with a version manager.

Comment: yeah, looks like there was some issue with 18.16.0 , I had installed it with conda. I upgraded to 18.16.1 today, and it's working now.

Comment: I had the same issue, fixed by updating to 18.16.1 too.
Note that you have to use the `conda-forge` channel for now:
`conda install -c conda-forge nodejs==18.16.1`